I want to open Instagram profile page feeds in a Flutter app
I want to open Instagram profile page feeds in a Flutter app. How can I do that? I've used a web view, but it's not working correctly. I just want to open the feeds of a particular user.
How can I do that? I've used a web view, but it's not working correctly. I just want to open the feeds of a particular user.

Did you try to launch https://www.instagram.com/{username} with AndroidIntent package?

First you need to have a account in

instagram-basic-display-api

then you can get a access token which needs to be passed in api to get the  feeds of a particular user
GET https://graph.instagram.com/{api-version}/{user-id}
  ?fields={fields}
  &access_token={access-token}

This api will return the data you are looking for then you can display the data in which ever format you want
for more details refer to this documentation
